# grep match end of line

Tags: linux, grep

I have bunch of files containing the lines having label="some value". what I would like to do is to fetch those lines which does not have ", /> or as a matter of fact anything after that.

desired o/p

```
label="Relation From a Connector
```

I am doing something like this:

```
grep -rni "label="\" * | grep -v \"$
```

and getting this non desired o/p

```
label="Graceful Restart Helper"/>
label="BGP Route Reflector Policy"
```

Comment: Is "output" really too long a word to write it out? Also, your output *is* a couple of lines who don't end in ". What's your question?

Comment: my desired output is a couple of lines which don't end in " for example

`label="Relation From a Connector`

Comment: `label="Graceful Restart Helper"/>` doesn't end in ", so it seems to qualify for me. Please add a specific question to the ... question. It's always a bad sign if there is no question mark

Comment: yes you are right my question was ambiguous I have edited it and please let me know if I made myself clear with the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to "\r\n" line endings in which case `grep -v \"$` will not trigger because there is a carriage return character after the `"` and before the end of line. If this is the case then filter through

```
grep -E -v '"^M?$'
```

where `^M` is control-M.